# Create Raw API NodeJS without framework

Tags: node.js, api

I'm writting raw API only NodeJS. 
my problem is server return  [object object] not JSON 
Here is my code:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = request;
  let body = [];
  request.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    // BEGINNING OF NEW STUFF

    response.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // Note: the 2 lines above could be replaced with this next one:
    // response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };

    response.write(body);
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(2018);
```

Anyway Thank for support me :)

Comment: Have you try `JSON.stringify(object)`?

Comment: of course, It return "[object object]"  :(

Comment: Your code is work, the possible problem is in request.

Comment: OK, I got it, Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `response.write`. It's expecting a string, not a JS object, so you need to stringify the response:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = request;
  let body = [];
  request.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    // BEGINNING OF NEW STUFF

    response.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // Note: the 2 lines above could be replaced with this next one:
    // response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    const responseBody = { headers, method, url, body };

    response.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(2018);
```

Comment: Fixed `body` to `responseBody` in the code. The above worked just fine for me. I ran `curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:2018` and got the expected output. If it doesn't work for you, something else is going on if you're pasting it exactly.

Comment: ok I got it
the problem is in my request
when I used XML request, it didn't work
but when I used ajax, it worked .